# How to get an array of words from paragraph in Swift?

Tags: arrays, string, swift, words

If I have some sentences like the ones below,

```
"Hello everyone. This is a sentence."
```

how can I use Swift to get an array like this

```
var words = ["Hello", "everyone", "This", "is", "a", "sentence"]
```

I would also need a way of being able to remember where each word is in the original string, and where full stops and commas were. So that if I were to make this array of words back into the same string, it would read

```
"Hello everyone. This is a sentence."
```

Thanks!

Comment: Never mind, I will just store all the punctuation separately with it's index and put it back in after/

Comment: Why do you need to do that? Why can't you just store the original string?

Comment: Because I need to be able to manipulate the words and do things with them, then return the original sentence. I can't change the words if there are punctuation marks included with them.

Comment: Ok, I posted a possible solution.

Answer (score 3):

Substrings broken down by word is built right in to Cocoa:

```
let s = "Hello everyone. This is a sentence."
var arr = [String]()
s.enumerateSubstringsInRange(s.startIndex..<s.endIndex, options: .ByWords) { 
    ss, r, r2, stop in
    arr.append(ss)
}
// now arr is ["Hello", "everyone", "This", "is", "a", "sentence"]
```

(But the rest of your spec makes no sense to me, so I omitted it. You can see how to work out where the words come from, since the two ranges `r` and `r2` tell you all about it.)

Answer (score 1):

With this you can parse the sentence in a structured way, such that you can modify words and be able to reconstruct the full sentence at any point.

The way to do this is:

1. Parse the sentence in a list of tokens which includes words, punctuation and spaces, in order.
2. Wrap each token in a "Token" class which makes access a bit more convenient, specifically, lets you query quickly if a token is a word.
3. Then you can filter using `isWord` whenever you need the list with only words, and modify them.
4. The modifications will reflect in the tokens array. So when you want to construct the full sentence again, you just have to join the tokens array.

Implementation:

```
let input = "Hello everyone. This is a sentence."

class Token {
    var text: String
    var isWord: Bool {
        return !(text == " " || text == ".")
    }
    init(text: String) {
        self.text = text
    }
}

let options: NSLinguisticTaggerOptions = .OmitOther
let schemes = [NSLinguisticTagSchemeLexicalClass]
let tagger = NSLinguisticTagger(tagSchemes: schemes, options: Int(options.rawValue))
let range = NSMakeRange(0, (input as NSString).length)
tagger.string = input
var parts : [String] = [] // here we put all the parts including spaces and punctuation signs, such that we can reconstruct sentence at any time
tagger.enumerateTagsInRange(
    range,
    scheme: NSLinguisticTagSchemeLexicalClass,
    options: options) {
        (tag, tokenRange, _, _) in

        let token = (input as NSString).substringWithRange(tokenRange)
        parts.append(token)
}

println(parts) //"[Hello,  , everyone, .,  , This,  , is,  , a,  , sentence, .]"
let tokens = parts.map{Token(text: $0)} // wrap the parts in a data structure to handle data more conveniently
let words = tokens.filter{$0.isWord} // get the tokens with only words, if you need them separatedly.
words[1].text = "world" // manipulate a word - this will reflect in the stored sentence
let text = join("", tokens.map{$0.text}) // "Hello world. This is a sentence."
```

Answer (score 0):

Building on @matt 's idea, you can build an array with **enumerateSubstringsInRange**, but also add punctuation characters as separate items in the array. Then also create a function that can determine if a string is punctuation using a character set when you goto work with the array. 
See below:

```
func checkCharSet(part:String, cSet:NSCharacterSet) -> Bool{
    let check = part.rangeOfCharacterFromSet(cSet)
    return (check != nil) ? true : false
}

func isPunctuation(part:String) -> Bool{
    let punctSet = NSCharacterSet.punctuationCharacterSet()
    return checkCharSet(part, punctSet)
}    

func isHexadecimal(part:String) -> Bool{
    let hexadecimal = NSCharacterSet.alphanumericCharacterSet()
    return checkCharSet(part, hexadecimal)
}
```

Then utilizing these two functions we can build our array accordingly.

```
let s = "Hello everyone. This is a sentence."

var arr = [String]()
var part:String = ""


s.enumerateSubstringsInRange(s.startIndex..<s.endIndex, options: .ByComposedCharacterSequences) { (
    ss, r, r2, stop) -> () in

    if isHexadecimal(ss){
        part += ss
    }else{
        arr.append(part)
        arr.append(ss)
        part = ""
    }
}
```

Printing out and filtering results:

```
let wordsOnly = arr.filter({isHexadecimal($0)})
let punctOnly = arr.filter({isPunctuation($0)})

println("\(arr)")
println("\(wordsOnly)")
println("\(punctOnly)")
```

http://www.swiftstub.com/873988306/?v=gm

Comment: But that doesn't solve the problem of the punctuation.

Comment: @Michael L Ok, I think this solution is more what you are looking for.

Comment: @MichaelL made minor change, as it occurred to me that saving the space in the array is necessary as well..

Answer (score -2):

@Ixx, I don't think your Token class is very useful.  Here are the modifications I would make:

```
import Cocoa

let input = "Hello everyone. This is a sentence."

let options: NSLinguisticTaggerOptions = .OmitOther
let schemes = [NSLinguisticTagSchemeTokenType]
let tagger = NSLinguisticTagger(tagSchemes: schemes, options: Int(options.rawValue))

let range = NSMakeRange(0, (input as NSString).length)
tagger.string = input

var parts: [String] = [] // here we put all the parts including spaces and punctuation signs, such that we can reconstruct sentence at any time
var words: [String] = []

tagger.enumerateTagsInRange(
    range,
    scheme: NSLinguisticTagSchemeTokenType,
    options: options) {

    (tag, tokenRange, _, _) in

        let part = (input as NSString).substringWithRange(tokenRange)
        parts.append(part)

        if tag == "Word" {
            words.append(part)
        }
}


println(parts) 
println(words)

--output:--
[Hello,  , everyone, .,  , This,  , is,  , a,  , sentence, .]
[Hello, everyone, This, is, a, sentence]
```

Or, for maximum flexibility you could add a tokenType to the Token class and filter the tokens array using the tokenType property.  For the scheme`NSLinguisticTagSchemeTokenType`, the token types are Word, Punctuation, Whitespace, or Other--which are the only token types the op needs to know about.

```
class Token {
    var text: String
    var tokenType: String

    init(text: String, tokenType: String) {
        self.text = text
        self.tokenType = tokenType
    }
}

let input = "Hello everyone. This is a sentence."

let options: NSLinguisticTaggerOptions = .OmitOther
let schemes = [NSLinguisticTagSchemeTokenType]
let tagger = NSLinguisticTagger(tagSchemes: schemes, options: Int(options.rawValue))

let range = NSMakeRange(0, (input as NSString).length)
tagger.string = input

var parts: [String] = [] // here we put all the parts including spaces and punctuation signs, such that we can reconstruct sentence at any time
//var words: [String] = []
var tokens: [Token] = []

tagger.enumerateTagsInRange(
    range,
    scheme: NSLinguisticTagSchemeTokenType,
    options: options) {

    (tag, tokenRange, _, _) in

        let part = (input as NSString).substringWithRange(tokenRange)
        parts.append(part)

        tokens.append(
            Token(text: part, tokenType: tag)
        )
}


println(parts) //"[Hello,  , everyone, .,  , This,  , is,  , a,  , sentence, .]"

let words = tokens.filter({$0.tokenType == "Word"})

println(
    words.map({$0.text}  //[Hello, everyone, This, is, a, sentence]
)
```

Comment: This should be a comment. Your are copying my entire answer just to make a minor, convenience improvement. I didn't give this much thought as it's not even clear what the TO needs and if this approach is usable at all. Glad to improve my answer if you add it as a comment - the code can be posted e.g. in http://swiftstub.com/

Comment: @Ixx: You know, I'm the one who upvoted your post.   I'm just trying to help the op.  *This should be a comment.*--The code would be unreadable in a comment.

Comment: I didn't want to come over as overly irritated, it's just bad etiquette to copy an answer to make rather minor improvements. Logically the TO would select your answer, since it's an improved version, ignoring the fact that the original idea and work is in mine. Thanks for the upvote but the point stands... concerning the code, that's why I suggested an external site like swiftstub.com